# Converting json objects in c# strings

Tags: c#, json-deserialization, package.json

I have this

```js
[
    {"type":"knife","knifeNO":"1","knifeName":"Shadow Daggers | Crimson Web","knifeEx":"Field Tested","knifeFv":" 0.3297","price":"42 keys","inspect":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198041444572A6024013354D17188164719027219402"},
    {"type":"knife","knifeNO":"2","knifeName":"Shadow Daggers | Urban Masked","knifeEx":"Field Tested","knifeFv":" 0.1972","price":"free","inspect":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198033359234A6046089123D2785026076714870254"}, 
    {"type":"gun","gunNo":"1","gunName":"StatTrak™ P90 | Trigon","gunEx":"Battle-Scarred","gunFv":"0.7393","price":"free","inspect":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198033359234A6042004711D7065101632830923871"},
    {"type":"gun","gunNo":"2","gunName":"M4A1-S | Atomic Alloy","gunEx":"Minimal Wear","gunFv":"0.1102","price":"2 keys","inspect":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198041444572A5899345580D13988253999937991086"}  
]
```

.json file(json array of objects) and I want to pull for the file the value pairs (like type:"knife") and make them C# strings so I can use them on one project that I am working on! But I cannot make it work and I tried a lot of things!

Could someone help me?

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. Show your best try and we will help you improve it until it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with multiple difference classes of objects (i.e. guns and knives) that have different properties, you could consider serializing them as `dynamic` objects and using them that way via the [`DeserializeObject<T>()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) method exposed by JSON.NET:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// Example of your JSON Input
var input = "{your-huge-array-here}";   
// Serialized weapons
var weapons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic[]>(input);
// Go through each type as expected
foreach(dynamic gun in weapons.Where(w => w.type == "gun"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Gun Number: {0}, Gun Name: {1}",gun.gunNo,gun.gunName);
}
foreach(dynamic knife in weapons.Where(w => w.type == "knife"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Knife Number: {0}, Knife Name: {1}",knife.knifeNO,knife.knifeName);
}
```

Depending on what you need, you could change the contents of your `foreach` loop to actually populate strings, build your own custom classes, etc.

**Example**

You can [see a very basic demonstration of this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UICjkZ) and an example of the output that you provided below :

[image]

Comment: Good one. You have typos that you probably want to fix. knive.kniveNo should be knife.kniveNo. gun.gunNo should be gun.gunNo

Comment: Thanks. It was a bit confusing with regards to the properties being correct as some were `NO` while others were `No`. I've adjusted the answer accordingly.